# While webscraping a website in python I don't get the expected response but just a script tag containing a few line of codes

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a site in python, the payload is right and everything works but when I get the response of the site which would normally be the source code of the html page I instead, get just a script tag with some error written in it. See the response I get enclosed :

```
b'<script language="JavaScript">\nerr = "";\nlargeur = 1024;\nif (screen.width>largeur) { document.location.href="accueil.php?" +err;\t}\nelse { document.location.href="m.accueil.php?largeur=" +screen.width +\'&\' +err;\t}\n</script>'
```

Information :

after looking at the site it seems that it uses google analytics, I don't really know about what it is but maybe because of the preview things, it can't load the page since i'm not accessing it by a navigator.

Comment: It looks like the page is using JavaScript to load the content. You may examine all the requests being made and maybe find another one or use tools like Selenium.

Comment: Have you tried feeding URL/accueil.php to your scraper? What does it return then?

Comment: When feeding URL/accueil.php to my scraper it retrurns the correct html and there is no script thing or errors.

Comment: Add the shortest code to reproduce the issue to the question via [edit]. For guidance please see [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

What tool are you using to webscrape? Tools like beautiful soup parse pre-loaded HTML content. If a website uses client-side rendering and JavaScript to load content, often times HTML parsers will not function.

You can instead use an automated browser that interacts with a website just as a regular user would. These automated browsers can operate with or without a GUI. Automated browsers when run without a GUI (also known as a headless browser) take up less time and resources than running them with a GUI. [Here's](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) a fairly exhaustive list of headless browsers you can use. Note that not all are compatible with Python.

As Buran mentioned in the comments Selenium is an option. Selenium is very well documented and has a large community following so it's easy to find helpful articles or tutorials. It's a multi-driver so it can run different types of browsers (firefox, chrome, etc.), both headless and with a GUI.

Comment: I'm using beautiful soup, I'm gonna take a look at selenium to see if that might help me.